# How do I extract data from the same row of a maxif result on excel?

Tags: excel-formula

So I have a data set converted from a stock chart in 1 minute time increments and I want to extract key data points from the data set.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RHpo.png)

The problem I am running into is when I attempt to use the INDEX function to match the MAXIF and MINIF results, the time criteria does not follow through:
The first function to extract the Low of Day from this data set:

=MINIFS(E:E, B:B, ">09:30", B:B, "<16:00")

The second function I'm attempting to pull the time of when the Low of Day data point is pulled from:

=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MINIFS(E:E, B:B, ">09:30", B:B, "<16:00"),E:E,0))

The result I get is **8:52 AM**, which is outside of the time criteria I have set. It appears that the function seems to pull the very first instance that matches the MINIF function result, disregarding the time criteria altogether.

So also I want to keep in mind that I want to use a function that does not rely on hunting down individual cells as I'm hoping the end goal is to automate a data extraction process to export all the significant data points into a new excel sheet, and doing this over the course of several hundred to thousands of data sets.

Ideally I'd like to have a function that can reference the exact data point that was first extracted to pull other significant data from the same row and avoid possibly referencing the wrong data point just because it's a duplication elsewhere.

Comment: This is probably because there are duplicates of 2.06 in column E. 
What you can try is :
The match statement : =MATCH(1,(MINIFS(E:E, B:B, ">09:30", B:B, "<16:00")=E:E)*(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(R1,C1))<B:B)*(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(R2,C2))>B:B),0)
The index statement : =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,(MINIFS(E:E, B:B, ">09:30", B:B, "<16:00")=E:E)*(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(R1,C1))<B:B)*(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(R2,C2))>B:B),0),E:E,0))
Replace R1,C1 and R2,C2 with the row and column of the cell in which you have entered the times 09:30 and 16:00 respectively. This will produce numbers like 0.395833 and 0.666667 respectively.

Comment: The problem is that the rows will most likely be different depending on the data set (some will not have any data until 08:00 for example), so I will need to use the time ranges to pinpoint the row I want, then do an index. If that is at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following array formula, which needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=INDEX(B2:B10,MATCH(SMALL(IF(B2:B10>"09:30"+0,IF(B2:B10<"16:00"+0,E2:E10)),1),IF(B2:B10>"09:30"+0,IF(B2:B10<"16:00"+0,E2:E10)),0))
```

...and adjust the ranges accordingly.  For efficiency, though, I would suggest that you avoid whole column references.

If the range grows over time, consider converting your data into a Table.  The references will automatically adjust as rows are added or removed.

Notice that `+0` is added to the time.  This is to coerce the string value into a true time value.

**EDIT**

Since it looks like you don't want to convert your data into a Table, here's an alternative that uses defined names instead.  Here too, the ranges will automatically adjust as rows are added/removed.  Note that it uses Column B to determine the last row.

First, define the following names (change the sheet names accordingly)...

```
Name:  LastRow
Refers to:  =MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,'Sheet 1'!$B:$B,1)

Name:  TimeColumn
Refers to:  ='Sheet 1'!$B$2:INDEX('Sheet 1'!$B:$B,LastRow)

Name:  LowColumn
Refers to:  ='Sheet 1'!$E$2:INDEX('Sheet 1'!$E:$E,LastRow)
```

Then try the following formula, which needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=INDEX(TimeColumn,MATCH(SMALL(IF(TimeColumn>"09:30"+0,IF(TimeColumn<"16:00"+0,LowColumn)),1),IF(TimeColumn>"09:30"+0,IF(TimeColumn<"16:00"+0,LowColumn)),0))
```

Comment: Would I be able to get away with making the ranges way wider than the data set? ie.. there are like 847 rows on this data set... can I get away with making it something like B2:B5000 ? If so, then I'll run with that!

Comment: If you know with certainty that the data will never extend beyond 5,000 rows, then sure that would be fine.

Comment: See my post, where I have added an alternative to converting your data to a Table.